# Complex string splitting

Tags: c#, regex, string, parsing, split

I have a string like the following:

```
[Testing.User]|Info:([Testing.Info]|Name:([System.String]|Matt)|Age:([System.Int32]|21))|Description:([System.String]|This is some description)
```

You can look at it as this tree:

```
- [Testing.User]
- Info
        - [Testing.Info]
        - Name
                - [System.String]
                - Matt
        - Age
                - [System.Int32]
                - 21
- Description
        - [System.String]
        - This is some description
```

As you can see, it's a string serialization / representation of a class `Testing.User`

I want to be able to do a split and get the following elements in the resulting array:

```
 [0] = [Testing.User]
 [1] = Info:([Testing.Info]|Name:([System.String]|Matt)|Age:([System.Int32]|21))
 [2] = Description:([System.String]|This is some description)
```

I can't split by `|` because that would result in:

```
 [0] = [Testing.User]
 [1] = Info:([Testing.Info]
 [2] = Name:([System.String]
 [3] = Matt)
 [4] = Age:([System.Int32]
 [5] = 21))
 [6] = Description:([System.String]
 [7] = This is some description)
```

How can I get my expected result?

I'm not very good with regular expressions, but I am aware it is a very possible solution for this case.

Comment: Do you have to serialise it into that format? Or can you put into into something like JSON or XML which would make it easier to deserialise?

Comment: @Steve Unfortunately, yes. It has to be this format :(

Comment: That makes it quite difficult since it's not in any kind of regular format.

Comment: Is this task to write the deserializer for the serialization of `Testing.User`? If it's **not**, is it possible to hunt down the deserializer for `Testing.User` and do your own re-engineering? It has been suggested above to serialize into another format, and I highly suggest that too if ***you/your team can make the call*** to switch the serialization library, especially if it's a bespoke one. Serialization shouldn't need to be re-developed in this day and age. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are more than enough splitting answers already, so here is another approach. If your input represents a tree structure, why not parse it to a tree?
The following code was automatically translated from VB.NET, but it should work as far as I tested it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Treeparse
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = "[Testing.User]|Info:([Testing.Info]|Name:([System.String]|Matt)|Age:([System.Int32]|21))|Description:([System.String]|This is some description)";
            var t = StringTree.Parse(input);
            Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class StringTree
    {
        //Branching constants
        const string BranchOff = "(";
        const string BranchBack = ")";
        const string NextTwig = "|";

        //Content of this twig
        public string Text;
        //List of Sub-Twigs
        public List<StringTree> Twigs;
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()]
        public StringTree()
        {
            Text = "";
            Twigs = new List<StringTree>();
        }

        private static void ParseRecursive(StringTree Tree, string InputStr, ref int Position)
        {
            do {
                StringTree NewTwig = new StringTree();
                do {
                    NewTwig.Text = NewTwig.Text + InputStr[Position];
                    Position += 1;
                } while (!(Position == InputStr.Length || (new String[] { BranchBack, BranchOff, NextTwig }.ToList().Contains(InputStr[Position].ToString()))));
                Tree.Twigs.Add(NewTwig);
                if (Position < InputStr.Length && InputStr[Position].ToString() == BranchOff) { Position += 1; ParseRecursive(NewTwig, InputStr, ref Position); Position += 1; }
                if (Position < InputStr.Length && InputStr[Position].ToString() == BranchBack)
                    break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit Do
                Position += 1;
            } while (!(Position >= InputStr.Length || InputStr[Position].ToString() == BranchBack));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Call this to parse the input into a StringTree objects using recursion
        /// </summary>
        public static StringTree Parse(string Input)
        {
            StringTree t = new StringTree();
            t.Text = "Root";
            int Start = 0;
            ParseRecursive(t, Input, ref Start);
            return t;
        }

        private void ToStringRecursive(ref StringBuilder sb, StringTree tree, int Level)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= Level; i++)
            {
                sb.Append("   ");
            }
            sb.AppendLine(tree.Text);
            int NextLevel = Level + 1;
            foreach (StringTree NextTree in tree.Twigs)
            {
                ToStringRecursive(ref sb, NextTree, NextLevel);
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            ToStringRecursive(ref sb, this, 0);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Result (click):
[image]

You get the values of each node with its associated subvalues in a treelike structure and you can then do with it whatever you like, for example easily show the structure in a `TreeView` control:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

### Using regex lookahead

You can use a regex like this:

```
(\[.*?])|(\w+:.*?)\|(?=Description:)|(Description:.*)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/wL8lF9/2)**

The idea behind this regex is to capture in groups `1`,`2` and `3` what you want.

You can see it easily with this diagram:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-14]   `[Testing.User]`
MATCH 2
2.  [15-88]  `Info:([Testing.Info]|Name:([System.String]|Matt)|Age:([System.Int32]|21))`
MATCH 3
3.  [89-143] `Description:([System.String]|This is some description)`
```

### Regular regex

On the other hand, if you don't like above regex, you can use another one like this:

```
(\[.*?])\|(.*)\|(Description:.*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/wL8lF9/3)**

Or even forcing one character at least:

```
(\[.+?])\|(.+)\|(Description:.+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your groups can be marked as

1. [Anything.Anything]
2. Anything:ReallyAnything (Letters & Numbers only:Then any amount of characters) after the first pipe
3. Anything:ReallyAnything (Letters & Numbers only:Then any mount of characters) after the last pipe

Then you have a pattern like:

```
"(\\[\\w+\\.\\w+\\])\\|(\\w+:.+)\\|(\\w+:.+)";
```

- `(\\[\\w+\\.\\w+\\])` This capture group will get the "[Testing.User]" but is not restricted to it only being "[Testing.User]"
- `\\|(\\w+:.+)` This capture group will get the data after the first pipe and stop before the last pipe.  In this case, "Info:([Testing.Info]|Name:([System.String]|Matt)|Age:([System.Int32]|21))" but is not restricted to it beginning with "Info:"
- `\\|(\\w+:.+)` Same capture group as previous, but captures whatever is after the last pipe, in this case "Description:([System.String]|This is some description)" but is not restricted to beginning with Description:"

Now if you were to add another pipe followed by more data (`|Anything:SomeData`), then `Description:` will be part of group 2 and group 3 would now be "`Anything:SomeData`".

Code looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        String text = "[Testing.User]|Info:([Testing.Info]|Name:([System.String]|Matt)|Age:([System.Int32]|21))|Description:([System.String]|This is some description)";
        String pattern = "(\\[\\w+\\.\\w+\\])\\|(\\w+:.+)\\|(\\w+:.+)";

        Match match = Regex.Match(text, pattern);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2]);
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[3]); 
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
[Testing.User]
Info:([Testing.Info]|Name:([System.String]|Matt)|Age:([System.Int32]|21))
Description:([System.String]|This is some description)
```

See working sample here... https://dotnetfiddle.net/DYcZuY

See working sample if I add another field following the pattern format here... https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mtc1CD

Answer (score 3):

To do that you need to use [balancing groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that is a regex feature exclusive the .net regex engine. It is a counter system, when an opening parenthesis is found the counter is incremented, when a closing is found the counter is decremented, then you only have to test if the counter is null to know if the parenthesis are balanced.
This is the only way to be sure you are inside or outside of the parenthesis:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
       string input = @"[Testing.User]|Info:([Testing.Info]|Name:([System.String]|Matt)|Age:([System.Int32]|21))|Description:([System.String]|This is some description)";

       string pattern = @"(?:[^|()]+|\((?>[^()]+|(?<Open>[(])|(?<-Open>[)]))*(?(Open)(?!))\))+";

       foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern)) 
           Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
   }
}
```

[demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3a%5b%5e%7c()%5d%2b%7c%5c((%3f%3e%5b%5e()%5d%2b%7c(%3f%3cOpen%3e%5b(%5d)%7c(%3f%3c-Open%3e%5b)%5d))*(%3f(Open)(%3f!))%5c))%2b&i=%5bTesting.User%5d%7cInfo%3a(%5bTesting.Info%5d%7cName%3a(%5bSystem.String%5d%7cMatt)%7cAge%3a(%5bSystem.Int32%5d%7c21))%7cDescription%3a(%5bSystem.String%5d%7cThis+is+some+description))

pattern details:

```
(?:
    [^|()]+    # all that is not a parenthesis or a pipe
  |            # OR
               # content between parenthesis (eventually nested)
    \(              # opening parenthesis
     # here is the way to obtain balanced parens
    (?> # content between parens
        [^()]+        # all that is not parenthesis 
      |               # OR
        (?<Open>[(])  # an opening parenthesis (increment the counter)
      |
        (?<-Open>[)]) # a closing parenthesis (decrement the counter)
    )*  # repeat as needed
    (?(Open)(?!)) # make the pattern fail if the counter is not zero

    \)
)+
```

`(?(open) (?!) )` is a conditional statement.

`(?!)` is an always false subpattern (an empty negative lookahead) that means : *not followed by nothing*

This pattern matches all that is not a pipe and strings enclosed between parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Regex is not the best approach for this kind of problem, you may need to write some code to parse your data, I did a simple example that achieve this simple case of yours. The basic idea here is that you want to split only if the `|` is not inside parenthesis, so i keep track of the parenthesis count. You will need to do some work around to threat cases where parenthesis is part of the description section for instance, but as I say, this is just a start point:

```
static IEnumerable<String> splitSpecial(string input)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int openParenthesisCount = 0;

    foreach (char c in input)
    {
        if (openParenthesisCount == 0 && c == '|')
        {
            yield return builder.ToString();
            builder.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            if (c == '(')
                openParenthesisCount++;
            if (c == ')')
                openParenthesisCount--;
            builder.Append(c);
        }
    }
    yield return builder.ToString();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "[Testing.User]|Info:([Testing.Info]|Name:([System.String]|Matt)|Age:([System.Int32]|21))|Description:([System.String]|This is some description)";
    foreach (String split in splitSpecial(input))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(split);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Ouputs:

```
[Testing.User]
Info:([Testing.Info]|Name:([System.String]|Matt)|Age:([System.Int32]|21))
Description:([System.String]|This is some description)
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a great/robust solution, but if you know your three top level items are fixed then you can hard code those into your regular expression.

```
(\[Testing\.User\])\|(Info:.*)\|(Description:.*)
```

This regular expression will create one match with three groups within it as you were expecting.  You can test it here: 
http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Edit:  Here's a full working C# example

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string input = @"[Testing.User]|Info:([Testing.Info]|Name:([System.String]|Matt)|Age:([System.Int32]|21))|Description:([System.String]|This is some description)";
            const string pattern = @"(\[Testing\.User\])\|(Info:.*)\|(Description:.*)";

            var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < match.Groups.Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[" + i + "] = " + match.Groups[i]);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```